# Type classes, associated families -> containers, keys, and elements: Who is who?

Tags: haskell, containers, idioms, type-families

Reading about [type families on haskellwiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Indexed_types), I see the example

```
class Collects ce where
  type Elem ce
  empty  :: ce
  insert :: Elem ce -> ce -> ce
```

This makes sense to me, as I use my (possibly counterproductive) OOP metaphors - an instance of Collects HAS A associated type (synonym) Elem ce.  The collection is somehow 'bigger' than the elements.

I'm confused by the example for associated data families because it doesn't fit that model.

```
 class GMapKey k where
   data GMap k :: * -> *
   empty       :: Gmap k v
   insert      :: k -> v -> GMap k v -> Gmap k v
```

The map collects vs and feels 'bigger' than the vs and the ks.  But it seems like GMapKey HAS an associated GMap, when I expected the relationship to go the other way.

When I'm choosing between data families and type synonym families, is this the pattern to follow (data families: container is the associated type, type synonym families: element is the associated type)?  Or is this IS A / HAS A distinction irrelevant, and the two examples could have been interchanged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest thinking of it this way: the `GMap` family is associated with `k`, and you must have a `GMap` type family instance associated with `k` for `k` to be used as a `GMapKey`.

The choice between these options is more dependent on your needs than anything else.  The `GMap k` approach is preferable when the key type dictates the map implementation: e.g. use an `IntMap` for `Int` keys, but use another type of `Map` for other keys...

Comment: Thanks Louis, that makes perfect sense.  I may have missed that point because the use case in front of me doesn't involve different implementations for different keys.  I'm only using type families to avoid what would otherwise be a multi parameter type class with functional dependencies.

Comment: @ImAlsoGreg I heartily agree with avoiding multiparameter type classes/functional dependencies is you can. Type families are much nicer.

Answer (score 4):

The IS A/HAS A relation is a bad metaphor here. A better intuition would be "ASSOCIATES WITH" or "SPECIALIZES (some type) TO". In practice it means that when you resolve a type

```
f :: GMapKey k => k -> GMap k v -> v
```

both the first and second parameters are polymorphic but must unify *together*. It's not necessary that one is contained within the other.

---

To decide which "direction" to use you have to think about how things generalize. If you define a class of "containers" which associated types for the "key" then you're saying that each container type "instantiates this class interface" on a single key. This is a many-to-one relationship since each "container" has a single associated "key" but "keys" can be the associated types for many containers. If you go the other way, you're stating that each "key" restricts to a specific kind of "container", but containers might have many different keys which can index them.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to remember that mnemonic until the deeper intuition sinks in :)

Comment: One way to learn (much) more about how Typeclasses work is to investigate Prolog. Type unification, typeclass unification, and logic programming are all similar paradigms.